# Find the count of output parameters in matlab function from C# through matlab dll

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

I created a matlab dotnet dll using deploytool.
Let us assume, I have the name of dll, name of the m file(method name), number of input arguments, count of output arguments, then I will be able to call the method.
I am able to find the count of input arguments by looking at the methods parameters. 
I am not able to find the count of output arguments.
Is there a way I can find the count of output arguments for the m file from C#.
I don't need the count of output arguments to invoke the method. I can put it as 1.
But, I need the count to access all the outputs.

This is the sample code:

```
function [a, b] = MyEcho ( a , b )
    disp 'a = ';
    disp(a);
    disp 'b = ';
    disp(b);
end
```

I use the below method to invoke the method in m file.

```
public void MyEcho(int numArgsOut, ref MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray[] argsOut, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray[] argsIn)
```

I use the below method to find the total input arguments. (a_in1, b_in1)

```
public MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray[] MyEcho(int numArgsOut, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray a_in1, MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray b_in1)
```

Comment: Show us an example of one of the m file methods.

Comment: I just added the example method. Thanks

Comment: That function does not appear to return anything.

Comment: I mean the output parameters a,b. I require the count of that.